# On existence of positive eigenvector in the left null space of a Q-matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am looking for a proof of the following statement:

> Let $n>0$ and $Q=(q_{ij})_{i,j = 1,\dots,n}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a [Q-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_rate_matrix) of a continuous-time Markov chain, i.e. a real square matrix such that
>
> 1. all row sums are zero, i.e. $\sum_{j=1}^n q_{ij} = 0$ for $i = 1,\dots,n$, and
> 2. all off-diagonal entries of are nonnegative, i.e. $q_{ij}\ge0$ whenever $i\neq j$ (it follows from (1) that the diagonal of $Q$ is non-positive).
>
> Then there is an entrywise nonnegative **left** eigenvector of $Q$ to the zero eigenvalue.

This result is taken from the book *Analysis and Geometry of Markov Diffusion Operators* written by Dominique Bakry, Ivan Gentil, and Michel Ledoux.

Clearly by (1), one has $\dim N(Q)>0$, therefore it holds that $\dim N(Q^t) >0$ so that $Q$ has a left eigenvector for the zero eigenvalue. I wonder why one can choose a *nonnegative* eigenvector, and if one can choose a *positive* eigenvector. Intuitivley I think of an application of Perron-Frobenius theorem but I don't know how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Q$ does not always have a positive left eigenvector in its left nullspace. Consider, e.g.
$$
Q=\pmatrix{-3&1&1&1\\ 1&-3&1&1\\ 0&0&-1&1\\ 0&0&1&-1}.
$$
The matrix has rank $3$. Hence its left null space is one-dimensional. It is easy to verify that the left nullspace is spanned by $(0,0,1,1)$, which is not positive.

However, in general, $Q$ always possesses a nonnegative left eigenvector for the zero eigenvalue. Pick any $t>\max_{i,j}|q_{ij}|$. Then $P=I+\frac1tQ$ is entrywise nonnegative. Therefore, Perron-Frobenius theorem guarantees that it has a nonnegative left eigenvector $v$ for the eigenvalue $\rho(P)$. Yet, $P$ is row-stochastic. Hence $\rho(P)=1$ and $v^TQ=0$.

Comment: Could you please give me a reference for a Version of the Perron Frobenius Theorem you are using? I could not find it or could not recognize it. Most versions i found do need the matrix to be irreducible under the assumption of nonnegative entries.

Comment: @residuence See e.g. Horn and Johnson, *Matrix Analysis*, 1/e, Cambridge University Press, Theorem 8.3.1, p.503. Or you may obtain this as a limiting case of the usual statement of Perron-Frobenius theorem for positive matrices.